# After searching data, make DBGrid cell change color

Tags: delphi

I'm building a function: after searching a value in DBGrid, it can count how many value and mark those cells (change cells' color).But I only made column change color.How can I do in one procedure?

```
procedure TfmMain.N_SearchClick(Sender: TObject);

var
searchname : String;
i: integer;
frmSearch : Tfrmsearch;
data_count : integer;

begin

  searchData := '';
  searchRow:=self.DBGrid.DataSource.DataSet.RecNo;
  searchname:= DBGrid.DataSource.DataSet.fieldbyname('FIELD').AsString;
  frmSearch:=Tfrmsearch.Create(self);

  try

     frmSearch.ShowModal;
     frmSearch.Visible:=true;

     for i := 0 to DBGrid.FieldCount do
     begin


       if ((Pos(searchData,DBGrid.DataSource.DataSet.Fields[i].AsString)>0) AND (CompareStr(searchData,'') <> 0)
       AND  (Pos('VALUE_',DBGrid.DataSource.DataSet.Fields[i].FieldName)>0)
       AND (searchRow=DBGrid.DataSource.DataSet.RecNo)) then
       begin

        data_count:=data_count+1;
        //DBGrid[DBGrid.Row,i-2].Color:=clLime;

       end;
     end;

      showmessage('countTotal: '+IntToStr(data_count));

  finally
  frmSearch.Free;
  end; 
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is something like this in the OnDrawColumnCell event of the grid:

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
    DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  //  Change font- and grid-color if showing search results
  if ShowingSearchResult then begin
    TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Brush.Color := clSilver;
    TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Font.Color := clBlue;
  end;
  TDBGrid(Sender).DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;
```

What you can do in the `OnDrawColumnCell` event is a bit limited, but should suffice for this case.  Iirc, at some point the `OnDrawDataCell` was added to allow for greater flexibility.

Of course, you would declare the `ShowingSearchResult` (boolean) variable as a field of your `TfrmSearch` and set it to `True` in your `N_SearchClick` procedure.  However, since that procedure shows the form modally and then frees it, you can possibly omit that variable entirely, so the `DBGrid1DrawColumnCell` could be just

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
    DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Brush.Color := clSilver;
  TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Font.Color := clBlue;
  TDBGrid(Sender).DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;
```

Comment: How can two different procedure (SearchClick and OnDrawColumnCell) transfer a value ?
How should I rewrite this statement `ShowingSearchResult` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, this is final code that I wrote.

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
    DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin    
    if (DBGrid.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName(Column.FieldName).AsString = searchData) 
and (searchRow=DBGrid.DataSource.DataSet.RecNo) then
    begin
      TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Brush.Color := $000080FF;
      DBGrid.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
    end;
end;
```